# Browser Is Cutting Part of The Content

Tags: html, browser

On one of my websites a post received a big amount of comments (1188 to be precise). As a result the length of this page is quite long (1,100,000 characters).

Despite being that large, the page used to display fine. Last week I launched a new design in HTML5, and now the browsers are cutting half-way through the comments, so that some of them don't get displayed (I am not 100% sure the re-design is the cause of the problem).

The weird thing is that the HTML source looks fine (all the comments are there) but the visualization on the browser cuts the page.

You can see it here: http://www.dailywritingtips.com/50-incorrect-pronunciations-that-you-should-avoid/

Any clue regarding the possible reason?

Comment: Could you post your source?

Comment: I just pasted the link. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the problem bro. You are setting max-height: 100000px to every element. Your body's height is more than 100000px so it restricts it to 100000px only. Remove this line from your CSS and things should work.

[image]

Comment: That line reads `100000px`. Are you saying that it's getting reduced for some reason?

Comment: @isherwood, I think even the 100000px limit is being reached. The OP just used the wrong number, but I believe he is right. I am applying the change right now.

Comment: * is a universal selector. That means it is applied on every element in the document. No element could attain a height greater than 100000px. But actually body originally has greater height than that (due to much content), and overflow:hidden was added (or inherited) to body. That restricted it to 100000px only.